# Help wanted - need descriptor for a partcular type/form of argument

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology, argumentation

I am writing a paper on cognition, and to simplify my discussion I need an adjective or descriptor for particular category of argument as follows: I am arguing for the necessity of a construct with a set of particular properties, but I do not produce an example or identity of that construct.  'Hypothetical' is wrong, as I am claiming necessity of existence. 'Existence proof' might work, except I am trying to distinguish it from using exemplars or testable properties (that are also existence proofs, I guess). Is there a descriptor that is helpful for this purpose? Or does my question have some flaw?

The specific domain (in case it helps) is theory of computation; although there are 'proofs' of the sort described in this domain, I cannot find any discussion of the nature of such a proof as distinct from (say) proof by exemplar; I am also going to ask some mathematicians, but it doesn't seem to be a semantic problem in math or symbolic logic.. in math you simply pick a symbol and imbue it with properties (There exists an x such that x has the following properties..).

Any help/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two descriptors that may fit the requirement are *non-constructive proof* and *pure existence proof*.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof):

> In mathematics, a *constructive proof* is a method of proof that demonstrates the existence of a mathematical object by creating or providing a method for creating the object. This is in contrast to a *non-constructive proof* (also known as an *existence proof* or *pure existence theorem*), which proves the existence of a particular kind of object without providing an example. For avoiding confusion with the stronger concept that follows, such a constructive proof is sometimes called an *effective proof*.

Answer (score 0):

How about *metaproof*?

I did a web search for the term, and found the following excerpt in a paper entitled, "'Metaproofs' (and their Cryptographic Applications)"<sup>1</sup>:

> We develop a non-interactive proof-system which we call “Metaproof” (µ-NIZK proof
>   system); it provides a proof of “the existence of a proof to a statement”. This metamathematical notion indeed seems redundant when we deal with proving N P statements, but in
>   the context of zero-knowledge theory and cryptography it has a large variety of applications.

<sup>1</sup> https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/495.pdf